# From a python3 script, how to I pipe a string into a bash program?

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, pipe, subprocess

As an example, here's what I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import Popen

message = "Lo! I am up on an ox."
Popen('less', shell=True).communicate(input=message)
```

As the last line, I also tried:

```
Popen('less', stdin=message, shell=True)
```

I can do what I want with:

```
Popen('echo "%s" | less' % message, shell=True)
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('less', shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('hey!!!'.encode('utf-8'))
print(p.communicate())
```

You can set up a `PIPE` for communication with the process

Comment: you don't need `p.stdin.write()` here. `utf-8` is wrong if OPs locale uses a different encoding. I don't see the requirement to redirect stdout in the question. Do not use `shell=True` in an answer aimed at a beginner. OP might be unaware that `shell=True` is not necessary or even harmful but a person who answer subprocess questions should know better

Answer (score 2):

@hyades answer above is certainly correct, and depending on what exactly you want might be best, but the reason your second example didn't work is because the `stdin` value must be file-like (just like unix). The following also works for me.

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode="w") as f:
     f.write(message)
     f.seek(0)
     Popen("less", stdin=f)
```

Comment: you should probably open the file using `r+` mode (though it works as is on my Ubuntu machine).

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to add `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` (to redirect child's stdin) as [@hyades suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29404758/4279) and `universal_newlines=True` (to enable text mode) to your code in order to pass a string to the child process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

message = "Lo! I am up on an ox."
Popen(['cat'], stdin=PIPE, 
      universal_newlines=True).communicate(input=message)
```

Don't use `shell=True` unless you have a reason.

Comment: This one solved the string to byte issue and another problem with larger output ("stdin: unexpected EOF in data, ..." from the subprocess).